Is minimum non-zero magnitude of computational basis transition amplitude $\langle x|U|y\rangle$ a super-multiplicative function of unitary $U$?
Given a $k$ qubit unitary $U$, let
$$
\rho(U) = \min_{x,y \in \{0,1\}^k\\ \langle x | U | y \rangle \neq 0} | \langle x | U | y \rangle |.
$$
Therefore, $\rho(U)$ is the magnitude of the smallest nonzero amplitude that $U$ can generate when acting on a computational basis state.
I'm trying to prove that this measure is super-multiplicative, i.e., that
\begin{equation}
\rho(UV) \geq \rho(U)\rho(V)
\end{equation}
for every pair of $k$-qubit unitaries $U$ and $V$. I suspect this to be true because, for example, $\rho(UU^\dagger) \geq \rho(U)\rho(U^\dagger)$ for all $U$. However, I cannot prove this.
My approach was to insert the completeness relation between $U$ and $V$, but then Cauchy-Schwarz does not help.
Does it seem sensible that this is super-multiplicative? I could not find a counterexample to the contrary. If so, any suggestions on proving it would be appreciated.

TL;DR: No, $\rho$ is not supermultiplicative. We can show it by considering big-angle $X$- or $Y$-rotations that compose to a small-angle rotation.

Let $R_X(\theta)=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}I-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}X$ so that $\rho(R_X(\theta))=\min(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}, \cos\frac{\theta}{2})$. For $\epsilon>0$, set $U_\epsilon:=R_X\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\right)$ and $V:=R_X\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Then
\begin{align}
\rho(U_\epsilon V)=\rho\left(R_X\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\right)R_X\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=\rho\left(R_X(\epsilon)\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\tag1
\end{align}
for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small. On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\rho(U_\epsilon)=\rho\left(R_X\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\tag2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\rho(V)=\rho\left(R_X\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tag3
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\rho(U_\epsilon V)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)=0\tag4
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\rho(U_\epsilon)\rho(V)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)=\frac12\tag5.
\end{align}
Consequently, as $\epsilon$ tends to zero, $\rho(U_\epsilon V)$ eventually becomes smaller than $\rho(U_\epsilon)\rho(V)$ contradicting supermultiplicativity.
